# Does the client stores the queries from consul registry in some cache?

Tags: consul, spring-cloud-consul

As the time taken by the clients to query consul for discovery will be more, does the client itself caches the registry or it queries consul for every request it has to make?

Answer (score 0):

Consul's [`/v1/catalog/service/:service`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/catalog#list-nodes-for-service) and [`/v1/health/service/:service`](https://www.consul.io/api-docs/health#list-nodes-for-service) endpoints both support [background refresh](https://www.consul.io/api/features/caching#background-refresh-caching) agent caching which allows client agents to locally cache & respond these requests, avoiding the need to constantly query the servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply -agent caching makes sense. Also, I was particularly asking on the overhead on a service. Let me elaborate on the scenario - Service (say A) calls another service (say B) using the ip address/url, but in our case Service A queries service registry first to discover service B and then send request. So won't the time taken to request Service B be more via service discovery(if so- that means A calling B with hardcoded url/address is better in terms of latency/time taken) ?   In terms of time, how much more time is taken by service to query consul when making call?

Comment: There would be some increased latency compared to hardcoding the address, but its typically negligible since the lookup should be made to the local Consul agent residing on the same host as the app. If you would rather hardcode the addresses in a file, but also want to use Consul for service discovery, a good alternative might be to template a config file using [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) that has a list of the upstream service addresses, and configure your application to read upstream endpoints from this file.